# What frequency does impedance matching become important

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I am in the process of making a motherboard for a Pentium III processor, with a bus speed of 66/100 MHZ and core clock of 800MHZ. What I need to know is at what frequency in general do I have to start paying attention to impedance matching of the data busses for any processor, and do I have to consider both core and bus frequency, or just the bus frequency? For example, can I wire wrap a board using the Pentium I, which also has a bus frequency of 66MHZ, and have it work(again, this is just an example. Wire wrapping one of those would be treacherous)?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on frequency (on the bus, not in the CPU) and the connection length.

The real question is: should you treat your interconnects as transmission lines? If the wavelength in the "wires" is a significant fraction - say 0.1 - of the wire length, then yes, and not only should source and load impedance match, the TL impedance should as well.

Assuming a velocity factor of 0.7, then at 100 MHz your wavelength would be about 4 meters, so you should start worrying at about 0.4 m. The "0.1" can vary depending on how conservative you want to be.

Comment: I'm planning on making the bus line extremely short, as in all of the main chips connected to it are a mere half a centimeter apart from the edges. So I should be safe if I just wing it?

Comment: Conventional TL design says you should be safe. But I hope you have a LA with a very high sample rate and glitch detector, and a similarly-spec'd DSO. (Remember that your DSO's sample rate should be at least 10x the FOI, even though the 'scope vendors try to tell you that 4x or even 2.5x is enough.) The Intel data sheets on the processor, bridge chips, etc., should also give you some clues about how "clean" the signals need to be.

Comment: @Jaca: Oh, p.s.: Even though your interconnect won't necessarily be the right impedance, the line drivers and receivers are nevertheless designed to work into that impedance from a pure DC standpoint. So if the GTL+ bus spec calls for 100 ohm termination at each end, you should do that. Or at least put a 50 ohm R at one end. :D Omit this and you may get severe overshoot, ringing, etc.

Comment: Okay! I will. And more expensive equipment to buy, of fun.

Comment: You can always start out by using what you have, and look into renting/borrowing stuff if you actually have problems. Maybe you won't. :)

Comment: Let's hope not...